# Adding csv files to database skips odd lines

Tags: php, mysql, unzip

I've been uploading large text files to the server and adding them to the database with the following command:

```
mysql_query("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$ver.txt' INTO TABLE objects FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' ESCAPED BY '\\\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n'");
```

It was working fine, until I started sending zipped files and unpacking them on the server. For some reason, it started skipping every second line. I tried downloading the unzipped file, it is identical to the one I used to upload before.

I suspect line endings could be causing the problem. The files use `\r\n` line endings, but specifying `\r\n` in the SQL query didn't work correctly so I stuck with `\n`. Why does unzipping the files cause this problem now?

Comment: Does it work if you replace all the `\r\n` by `\n` before uploading the files? In which case, it should be too difficult to automate the replacement.

Comment: Sure, I could do that (by simply re-running the script that generated the files in the first place). I want to know why zipping-unzipping causes this issue though, because uploading the text file and adding it with the above command works fine, but zipping it on my machine and unzipping on the target doesn't, even though the files appear to be identical.

Comment: Is the source system for the zipped files 'windows' based? It uses 'crlf' as end-of-line by default. The other issue is that the mysql 'load data' utility is really pedantic about 'end-of-line' characters. Other 'csv' readers are more tolerant.

Comment: Yes, the files are created on Windows. Since the contents of the zipped-unzipped file seems to be identical to the original file (unless the FTP utility alters line endings?), why could the two files be treated differently by mysql?

Comment: @riv, maybe it's the other way. The "problem" could be that your FTP client automatically converts crlf to lf when transferring the files so you are not seeing any issue in that case. I think the simplest thing to do would be to automatically convert the line endings yourself before uploading the files.

Answer (score 0):

You should include an MD5 with each text file then check if server side before importing the files. For example, with something like this:

```
$goodMd5 = file_get_contents("$ver.md5");
$checkMd5 = md5_file("$ver.txt");

if ($goodMd5 != $checkMd5) die('Invalid MD5');

// Proceed...
```

That way you are absolutely sure you are dealing with the right data. If there's an error despite good MD5s, then the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Sorry, I updated the question because it seems that the problem is elsewhere. Not sure if I should've posted a new question instead.